# SAS ODS Output Incomplete

Tags: sas

I am trying to output to an excel workbook using ods. However, I am only getting some of the output. For example, the Summary Panel is not populating. The same code is working for some `proc freq` I did earlier. Also, how do I insert the TOC--I thought that was automatic.

Here is my code:

```
ods _all_ close;

ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP
file='\\psf\Home\Documents\ttest_750_091814.xls'
STYLE=Default
OPTIONS ( Orientation = 'landscape'
FitToPage = 'yes'
Pages_FitWidth = '1'
Pages_FitHeight = '100' );
ods graphics on;


proc format;
    value compF 0 = 'M'
                1 = 'F';    
run;

proc ttest data=ten;
    class comp;
    format comp compF.;
    var Sales;
    where id = "750";
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
ods html close;
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the FitToPage, Pages_FitWidth and Pages_FitHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Table of Contents comes from one of two options set:

- index='yes'
- contents='yes'

They give somewhat different results, so try both and keep whichever you find more useful.

See [Eric Gebhart's paper from SGF 2008](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/036-2008.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the TOC suggestion. I removed the tagsets and that solved it.